# How many characters can I have and do they expire?

Tags: diablo-iii

In *Diablo II*, you could have any number of characters in offline play. On closed Battle.net, characters could expire if you didn't play them.

How does *Diablo III* limit the number of characters I can have? Is there a maximum number? How do Hardcore and the different Realms factor in? Can characters expire from inactivity?

Comment: they can be all hardcore if you like, though you would have to delete the character that you first leveled to 10 to unlock hardcore mode

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[You can have 10 characters per server.](http://blues.incgamers.com/Posts/1/1/4/10/106643/10-character-limit) In addition, they can be any mix of hardcore and non-hardcore characters. I'm assuming 10 was chosen so that you can theoretically have 5 non-hardcore characters and 5 hardcore characters.

[Also, characters won't expire.](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4662237417#6)

Comment: It may also have been chosen to allow 5 each male and female characters, which IIRC is required for an achievement.

Comment: No, the achievements you're thinking of just requires you to level two characters of a certain class to level 60, without any specifications about gender: http://i.imgur.com/2CjHL.jpg

Answer (score 9):

Regarding character deletion/expiration:

> **Characters will not expire.**

Source: [Community Manager Kaivax](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4662237417#6)