# Will my Diablo 3 characters be deleted if I don't play them?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many characters can I have and do they expire?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67653/how-many-characters-can-i-have-and-do-they-expire)

With Diablo 2, if you didn't play your characters for, I believe, 90 days, then they would be deleted permanently.  Does the same thing happen in Diablo 3?

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate.  I searched before submitting and didn't see that question in the results.

Comment: Yeah, I did a fast search, too, but didn't find this one, either.  No downvotes, so it's all good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so.
The forums say they don't, and I have a character I created the day the game came out and did not play it at all, and it's still there.

If it ever disappears, I'll update this answer.